# How to upload multiple images in Yii framework?

Tags: php, yii

I have a question on uploading may images in Yii. Where should I put this code?

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
   'id'=>'topic-form',
   'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
   'htmlOptions' => array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'), 
)); ?>
```

Folks from the Yii forums also said to use this:

```
 $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
            'name' => 'images',
            'accept' => 'jpeg|jpg|gif|png', 
            'duplicate' => 'Duplicate file!', 
            'denied' => 'Invalid file type', 
        ));
```

Where should I put that also? What my problem is using those codes I can't select many image, I'm only allowed to select one image. What should I use to select more than one image?

One more thing, it has been recommended to me to use this:

```
if(!is_dir(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/ADD YOUR    PATH HERE!/'. $model->name)) {
              mkdir(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/ADD YOUR PATH HERE!/'.     $model->name))
                   chmod(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot').'/images/ADD YOUR PATH HERE!/'. $model->name)), 0755); 

}
```

Should I put this on the controller?

Comment: They are saying a lot of things - but who are "they"? (Aside: please don't write your questions entirely in lower case - we like to make things readable here. Remember that questions are for the benefit of future readers, not just the poster).

Comment: I'm sorry but what I'm calling they is from the Yii framework forums sorry again

Comment: Try this way http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/567/multiple-files-uploader-with-cmultifileupload/

Answer (score 0):

You can try EAjaxUpload. I use it and it's very good tool for multi uploading and also have a good documentation. Here is the link: [Yii EAjaxUpload extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/eajaxupload)

Comment: do we really need to always use extensions? Im still new to Yii framework so im still familiarizing the basics

Comment: This extension has some good features like drag and drop, progress percentage and multiple upload. You can easily implement this extension. I think you will need it in your project. I used it in many yii projects.